# Finding a curve that a function converges to

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Say I have a function $f\left(x\right)$ which does not have a limit as $x \to \infty$. My question is whether there is a method for finding another function $g\left(x\right)$ that the function converges to in the sense that the difference $f - g$ goes to $0$ as $x \to \infty$.

I am aware that there may be many such functions, so I am not expecting such a method to give all such functions, but hopefully at least one function $g\left(x\right)$ which is simpler to work with than $f$.

I'll give an example to convey my motivation here. Consider the function $f = {{1}\over{\exp{\left(1\over{x}\right)-1}}}$. If I want to know the behaviour as $x \to \infty$ and I expand the exponential in a power series and just keep the first term I get $f = {{1}\over{1 + {1\over{x}} - 1}}=x$, but when I look at the graph of $f$ it seems to actually converge to the function $y = x - {1\over2}$. I am wondering how I could find that out algebraically (by which I mean without looking at the graph). This is not about showing that $f$ in this example converges to $y = x - {1\over2}$; I am looking for a way by which I could find that function $y$ in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As in many questions,
the answer is Bernoulli,
but in this case the numbers,
not the inequality.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number.

You have
$f(x) = {{1}\over{\exp{\left(1\over{x}\right)-1}}}
$.

The Bernoulli numbers satisfy
$b(t)
=\dfrac{t}{e^t-1}
=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{B_m t^m}{m!}
$
where the
$B_m=
1, -\dfrac12, \dfrac16, 0, -\dfrac1{30}, ...
$.

Therefore
$b(1/x)
=\dfrac{1/x}{e^{1/x}-1}
$
so that
$f(x)
=xb(1/x)
=x(1 -\dfrac1{2x}+ \dfrac1{6x^2} -\dfrac1{30x^4}+ ...)
=x -\dfrac1{2}+ \dfrac1{6x} -\dfrac1{30x^3}+ ...
$.

Answer (score 0):

Linear asymptotes may be deduced as follows (if there are linear asymptotes)

$$m=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x$$

$$b=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-mx$$

Thus, the linear asymptote is then given by

$$f(x)\sim mx+b$$

Answer (score 0):

$e^{1/x}-1
=1/x+1/(2x^2)+...
=(1/x)(1+1/(2x)+...)
$

so

$1/(e^{1/x}-1)
=x/(1+1/(2x)+...)
=x(1-1/(2x)+...)
=x-1/2+...
$

Take more terms
to get more accuracy.